# How to use the checkbox value on a marketing cloud html form for creating lead in salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, landing-page

I have created an Html form on my marketing cloud landing page and I am creating a lead on the form submission using CreateSalesforceObject() function.
All the form fields are being captured well except one checkbox field.
I am using the request parameter to fetch the checkbox value but it's giving me error500.
Can anybody help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296953/how-to-try-catch-retrievesalesforceobjects-in-ampscript/296979#296979 use try catch around it to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need to define a true or false value.

If your HTML looks like this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="consent" value="true">
```

Then in your AMPscript code block, use the following syntax (obviously change the arguments as required):

```ampscript
  var @consent, @createLead

  set @consent = iif(RequestParameter('consent')==true,'true','false')

  set @createLead = CreateSalesforceObject(
        "Lead", 5,
        "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
        "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
        "Company", RequestParameter("company"),
        "Email", RequestParameter("email"),
        "Consent__c", @consent
       )
```

Comment: Thanks mate. it worked like magic. Also upon submission, I want to redirect to my 'Thanks for submission' page. how to do i do that. any clues?

Comment: Yes, simply add the [Redirect function](https://ampscript.guide/redirect/) after the CreateSalesforceObject function, like: `Redirect("https://mysubmissionpage.com")` or another CloudPage: `Redirect(CloudPagesURL(123))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eliot. Just one last query. is it possible that After the Lead has completed the form they should receive a confirmation email to their provided Email? IF they click the link to confirm, the Lead Records OwnerId in CRM should change. I am not sure how should i approach towards this.

Comment: @MikeT, that's a completely different question. I would suggest you create a new question for that. Also, SFSE isn't a free code-writing service, so please provide an example of what you have tried, so we can help you.