# Update Object in SF via cloudpage form submission

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, standard-objects, cloudpage

I have a use case where I am preparing a cloudpage form with mobile number input field.
Upon hitting submit, the mobile number should update in the sales and service cloud under **Mobile** field. I don't wish to individually update mobile numbers, its a bulk update.
this cloudpage will be sent out within in EDM where DE consists of (contact ID18, Account Name, Email, mobile phone (this field can be blank or have a number)) - still only want mobile to be updated, and this can be overwritten by the previous number or fill out a null field.

this is what my code looks so far:

```
%%[
var @Id, @MobilePhone
set @Id = AttributeValue("_subscriberKey")
  set @MobilePhone = RequestParameter("MobilePhone")
  set @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      "Contact", @Id
      , "MobilePhone", @MobilePhone
     )
]%%
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Update Your Details</h2>
      <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
         <label>Mobile Phone</label>
         <input type="text" name="MobilePhone" value="%%=v(@MobilePhone)=%%">
         <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true" />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
          %%[ if @updateRecord == 1 then ]%%
         <p>Record Updated</p>
      %%[ elseif @updateRecord == 0 then ]%%
        <p>Update Failed</p>
      %%[ endif ]%%
   </body>
</html>
```

I have already tested this once and received: 500 - Internal server error.

Please help guys!

Thanks heaps in advance
(im a new user of SFMC, so still learning) :)

Comment: can you please include your code as CODE, not as a screenshot?
One error that is immediately apparent is a spurious comma after `@mobilePhone` in your Update call. since updateSalesforceObject is terrible to debug without it, continue with wrapping it in a try catch function as described here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296953/how-to-try-catch-retrievesalesforceobjects-in-ampscript/296979#296979

Comment: @JonasLamberty included the code as code above, and fixing the comma

Comment: @JonasLamberty so ive put that entire code above between where it says AMPscript code in the code below, what's next steps?

<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
Platform.Load("core","1");
try {
</script>
<!--%%[
... AMPscript code ...
 
]%% -->
<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
} catch (ex) {
    Variable.SetValue("@error", true)
    Variable.SetValue("@errorMsg", Stringify(ex))
}
</script>

Comment: after the closing ampscript tag, put `%%=v(@errorMsg)=%%` which outputs the variable you set in the javascript snippet to contain the error you receive. then put it all on a cloudpage and preview it. you should get an error message displayed instead of just "500". (assuming that the error that triggered the 500 is in the ampscript, which is highly likely). then you can follow the error messages. it's typically some mandatory fields on the object you need to include, or formatting issues. the error message for updateSingleSalesforceObject is usually quite precise.

Comment: Your _SubscriberKey will be the ContactID, not AccountID. You'd need to get the AccountID first in order to update the Account object. You can lookup the Contact_Salesforce DE or refer to the AccountID field in your sendable Data Extension (if present). If there's a likelihood that the contact landing on the page was created within the last 15 mins and you've not included the Account in your sendable data, do a RetrieveSalesforceObjects() to get the Account ID for the Contact.

Comment: Thank you both! ive got the process working now - update code is in the description area above :)

Comment: @Macca - can you assist me with how to show the confirmation message can show up? for the 'record update' or 'failed update' please.. currently either of the messages show up in the bottom of the input type field and submit button 
need it to be more dynamic and show up on same screen under submit - whether updated or failed