# RetrieveSalesforceObjects from child BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to use the RetrieveSalesforceObjects() function to look-up an object from child BU but the sync is to Parent BU (and we have sync de in shared de).

Is there anything different I have to do when using this function? I seem to come across 500 error.

```
 SET @accountLookupByClientID = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Account", "Name, Trading_Name__c, Id", "Client_ID__c", "=", @clientid)
                SET @accountLookupByClientIDCount = RowCount(@accountLookupByClientID)
```

Comment: We need more context, can you share the whole code? Where are you running this - on a CloudPage?

Comment: Use a try catch around it for debugging, the retrieve function should produce meaningful errors instead of 500 error.  Your Retrieve function looks good, syntactically, btw. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296953/how-to-try-catch-retrievesalesforceobjects-in-ampscript/296979#296979