# AMPscript issue - Cannot update a contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect, custom-profile

I have built a custom profile center, i retrieved the contact's data from Sales Cloud via Marketing Cloud Connect. When i click on submit to update the data, nothing happened!

here's my AMPScript code :

```
%%[
SET @contactId = "0033z00002dqxqJAAQ"
IF NOT EMPTY(@contactId) THEN
    SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
        "Contact",
        "Salutation, FirstName,LastName,Email,Newsletter__c,Events__c,Offers__c,HasOptedOutOfEmail",
        "Id",
        "=",
        @contactId
    )
    IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) > 0 THEN
        SET @row = row(@subscriberRows, 1)
        SET @Salutation = field(@row, "Salutation")
        SET @FirstName = field(@row, "FirstName")
        SET @LastName = field(@row, "LastName")
        SET @Email = field(@row, "Email")
        SET @Newsletter = field(@row, "Newsletter__c")
        SET @Events = field(@row, "Events__c")
        SET @Offers = field(@row, "Offers__c")
        SET @HasOptedOutOfEmail = field(@row, "HasOptedOutOfEmail")
        IF @Newsletter == true THEN
            SET @Newsletterchk = "checked"
        ELSE
            SET @Newsletterchk = "unchecked"
        ENDIF
        IF @Events == true THEN
            SET @Eventschk = "checked"
        ELSE
            SET @Eventschk = "unchecked"
        ENDIF
        IF @Offers == true THEN
            SET @Offerschk = "checked"
        ELSE
            SET @Offreschk = "unchecked"
        ENDIF
        IF @Salutation == "Mr." THEN
            SET @GenderH = "checked"
        ELSEIF @Salutation =="Ms." THEN
        SET @GenderF = "checked"
        ENDIF
    ENDIF
    VAR @lname, @fname, @adressemail, @nl, @et, @off
    SET @fname = RequestParameter("firstname")
    SET @lname = RequestParameter("lastname")
    SET @adressemail = RequestParameter("email")
    SET @nl = Iif(RequestParameter("newsletter") == "on", "true", "false")
    SET @et = Iif(RequestParameter("events") == "on", "true", "false")
    SET @off = Iif(RequestParameter("offers") == "on", "true", "false")
    IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN
        SET @contactUpdate = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
            "Contact",
            @contactId,
            "FirstName",
            @fname,
            "LastName",
            @lname,
            "Email",
            @adressemail,
            "Newsletter__c",
            @nl,
            "Events__c",
            @et,
            "Offers__c",
            @off
        )
    ENDIF
ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: try wrapping the problematic function in a try catch to isolate the error https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296953/how-to-try-catch-retrievesalesforceobjects-in-ampscript/296979#296979

Comment: @JonasLamberty, Thank you for your comment. Actually I did, and I didn't find any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was about [RequestParameter](https://ampscript.guide/requestparameter/) function, i was trying to retrieve values from the id attribute instead of the name attribute.