# UpdateSingleSalesforceObject Custom Object with multiple types ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a question concerning the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject and did not find the right answer.
Normally it is not problem to update a custom object, but in this case, the custom Object has multiple types.

There is a Consent Object with a Consent Type field. Only if the right Type is selected, the field I want to update would be available. Ist this possible? To define type and field in one AMPScript?

Those two are not working (I tried without the type in the second one):

```
set @result_account = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Candidate_Consents__c','Candidate ID','Consent_Type__', 'Type_ID', 'Status__c', 'I do not Consent')

 set @result_account = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Candidate_Consents__c','Candidate ID','Status__c', 'I do not Consent')
```

Comment: a) your first sample line lacks the "c" at the end of `Consent_Type__`; 
b) wrap it in a try / catch to get a proper errormessage, similar to here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296953/how-to-try-catch-retrievesalesforceobjects-in-ampscript/296979#296979

Comment: Thx, I will try this. The missing c __c I already found before. That was a mistake from my side.